# How to print cookies in .ejs view engine

Tags: node.js, express

How May I print cookies value in the form attribute?

This is the code that I am trying.

```
if(req.body.remember_me){
    res.cookie("cookie_email_id", req.body.email);
    res.cookie('password', req.body.password);
}else{
    res.clearCookie("cookie_email_id");
    res.clearCookie("password");
}
```

and I have checked cookie in console and cookie is stored there please see
`document.cookie` :

`cookie_email_id=abc%40gmail.com; password=123456789`

Comment: What are you trying to do with the cookie value, are you trying to assign it to a variable for processing (such as finding a user db record)?

Comment: No, I want to autofill form value with cookie variable name

Answer (score 6):

To pre-fill form inputs through ejs, first of all you need to set the cookies via res.cookie() .To autofill these values in a form field .You need to get the cookies from the request and assign it to your render method.

For this you can use cookie-parser middleware like this and get the cookie values in req.cookies/req.signedCookies.

```
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Cookies that have not been signed
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies)

  // Cookies that have been signed
  console.log('Signed Cookies: ', req.signedCookies)
})

app.listen(8080)
```

From the route you can call your ejs render method with all the properties to autofill

something like

```
res.render('user_profile',{name:req.cookies.name, age:req.cookies.age})
```

You can then place the values in your ejs form fields as like

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="%name%"/>
<input type="text" id="age" value="%age%"/>
```

Comment: This gives me undefined because Node.js doesn't know who's browser to get the cookies from until the client opens the file, but the page is already rendered.

Answer (score 3):

When you response , try this:

```
res.render("your_page", {email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password});
```

And set `email` and `password` to value of input (with `ejs`).

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be retrieved from `req.headers.cookie` and the same can be passed to EJS template or anywhere else based on requirement.

**For Example :**

Print cookie in console:

```
router.get("/example"), (req, res) => { console.log(req.headers.cookie); }
```